# meaning of #define in Windows resources source file

Tags: c++, visual-studio, winapi

I am reading a tutorial about creating simple windows with the help of winapi for c++ in vs

In the resource.h I see

```
#define IDC_ERRORTEXT                   1001
```

and then in resource.rc I see

```
EDITTEXT        IDC_ERRORTEXT, 4, 20, 176, 20, ES_MULTILINE |
ES_AUTOVSCROLL | ES_READONLY | NOT WS_BORDER | WS_VSCROLL
```

Why is 1001 used for `IDC_ERRORTEXT` defining? Is it some random number? or does it define the number of characters possible here?

Note that I was trying to change it to 10 - it wont work
then I changed it to 1005- it worked
then I changed to 10000- again didnt work

I understand that it is an identifier, but which identifier should I use if for example I add there another edittext control?

Lets say I am going to add other

```
#define IDC_ERRORTEXT2                   ?
 #define IDC_ERRORTEXT3                   ?
 #define IDC_ERRORTEXT4                   ?
```

Which idetnifiers should I use there?

Comment: The number `1001` has a special meaning for the API. Since it does **not** carry a meaning for the human reader, it is given a symbolic name (`IDC_ERRORTEXT`) by the header file. It is not a random, but a very *specific* number, with a "name" for easier handling.

Comment: The `ID` means *identifier*

Comment: If the tutorial has you hand-coding the resource file and these values, then it should also tell you what ranges to use for those values. If not, find a different book or tutorial.

Comment: There is no special meaning to 1001, other than that it is the next one after 1000.  These numbers are normally assigned by the resource editor, the one that gives you the WYSIWYG view on a dialog resource.  That editor starts assigning control IDs at 1000.  Editing the resource.h file should not be a problem and there is no clear reason why "it doesn't work", other than that VS hassles you a bit about it, it doesn't like you doing both.  Using the editor is the simplest way to stay out of trouble.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comments

Answer (score 2):

The 1001 constant is an identifier for the `EDITTEXT` control.

> Lets say I am going to add other (...) Which idetnifiers should I use there?

You simply use another unique value, say 1002, 1003, 1004.

Comment: Thank you very much wilx

Comment: I guessed I could simply use some other value (with what I experimented  I was trying to change it to 10 - it wont work then I changed it to 1005- it worked then I changed to 10000- again didnt work. I just wonder what is the principle of giving the numbers. But as you recommended 1002, 1003, 1004 worked :)

Comment: Side note: Normally devs will use the built in visual studio resource editor for adding/editing their resources. It takes care of all the number maintenance for you.

Comment: Resource identifiers need to be unique only within their respective scope. You can have string IDs with the same value of bitmap IDs, for example. And you can reuse control IDs, as long as they do not have the same parent (or aren't otherwise relevant to your application, like IDs for static controls). Assigning globally unique values is safe, but when you start to run out of IDs you need to understand, where uniqueness is strictly required.